# Javascript: Image complete/load event is not fired

Tags: javascript, image, callback

I've this code that I want to use to check aspect ratio of an image, before to load it.

My problem is that function callback binded with **image.complete** events is not triggered.

Where I am wrong?

```
checkAspectRation : function(file){

    var reader = new FileReader();
    /*Read the file*/
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    /*Callback */
    reader.onloadend = (function() {

        var image = new Image();

        image.complete = function() {
            // access image size here 
            console.log("Width: " + this.width);
            console.log("Height: " + this.height);
        };

        image.src = reader.result;

        console.log(image);
    });

},
```

This is the value of image after loading:

[image]

**[EDIT]**

I changed in this way but it doesn't still work

```
checkAspectRation : function(file){

    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        // access image size here 
        console.log("Width: " + this.width);
        console.log("Height: " + this.height);
    };

    var reader = new FileReader();

    /*Callback */
    reader.onloadend = (function() {
        console.log(image);
        image.src = reader.result;    
    });

    /*Read the file*/
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
},
```

Comment: `complete` is not an event handler. You're thinking of `onload`.

Comment: Thanks you @JJJ but I have the same result using `onload`

Comment: Set onload before calling readAsDataURL

Comment: Thanks @JohnLondon. I changed as suggested, but the problem is still present. I edit the question with changes.

Answer (score 0):

Solved changed:

```
var image = new Image();
```

with

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
```

This works fine:

```
checkAspectRation : function(file){

    var reader = new FileReader();

    /*Callback */
    reader.onloadend = function() {

        //var image = new Image();
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.onload = function() {
            // access image size here 
            console.log("Width: " + this.width);
            console.log("Height: " + this.height);
        };

        image.src = reader.result;

    };

    /*Read the file*/
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
},
```